# how to select particular value from uib-typeahead in input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, yeoman-generator-angular

Hello everyone i am trying to select single value from uib-typeahead group of values,can any buddy tell me how can i achieve that.Thank you

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 nopadding">
   <label for="company">Company/Project*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="formInfo.company" 
      name="company" ng-disabled="loadingCompanyDetails" ng-blur="fetchCompanyDetail()"
     ng-change="resetLocation()" placeholder="Company Name" 
     uib-typeahead="company for company in companyList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
     id="company" autocomplete="off" required>
  </div>
```

above is my code where on typing any value its giving auto list of options ,so how can i get single value as default selected value from that list,at first time i dont want to type in input tag and it gives list of values,instead of this i want it will select by default one value out of that list.

here is controller code:

```
        $scope.fetchCompanyList = function () {
      uploadService.getCompanyList()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.companyList = response.data;
          },
          function (error) {
            $scope.errorMessage = error.status + " : " + error.statusText;
            if (error.status === 401) {
              loginService.authenticationError();
            }
          }
        );
    };

    /**
     * Method to fetch company details
     */
    $scope.fetchCompanyDetail = function () {
      if ($scope.formInfo && $scope.companyList.indexOf($scope.formInfo.company) >= 0) {
        $scope.company = {};
        $scope.loadingCompanyDetails = true;
        $scope.hideCompanyAboutUs = true;
        $scope.getCompanyDetails($scope.formInfo.company);
      }
    };
```

here is my screen shots of application.
when user type its give list of options.
[image]

what actually i want it will select by default one selected value in input box.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please post `companyList` object

Comment: here is my controller code..

Comment: Please post above mentioned code to your question

Comment: check it now...

Comment: I still don't see `companyList` object. Please post it

Comment: @ZaifWarm Please post a jsfiddle or make a code snippet in your question. Be sure that it works and reproduce the issue. That will clear the question of missing code.

Comment: @MaximShoustin let me check i will put there.by the way thanks for giving your value able time for my question..thank you..

Comment: @MaximShoustin $scope.companyList is the only object in which its storing the list of company's  look at this code:$scope.companyList = response.data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your full code but enough to define `ng-model`.

I suggest you to use `id` to identify selected object:

```
  $scope.company = {
    id: 2, 
    name: 'Bert'
  };
```

And your input will look like:

typeahead-loading="loading"
     typeahead-no-results="noResults"
     class="form-control input-sm"
     autocomplete="off" required>

**JS**:

```
$scope.companyList = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Aaron'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bert'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Cesar'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'David'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'Elsa'}];


  $scope.company = {
    id: 2, 
    name: 'Bert'
  };                  

  $scope.selectTypeAhead = function($item)  {
    $scope.company.id = $item.id;
  };
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7biaZaAgOwIxFHEZUAdk?p=preview)</kbd>

---

So if you don't get proper model - that means `formInfo.company` is not defined properly.

You can easily validate it by typing in HTML:

```
<pre>{{formInfo|json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addision, you can set value by id:

In ES6

```
$scope.company = $scope.companyList.filter(comp => comp.id == 2)[0]

$scope.companyList = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Aaron'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bert'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Cesar'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'David'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'Elsa'}];
```